How to write a C++ function that deletes a pointer instead of a macro
I found a macro in legacy code that deletes a pointer. I tried to replace it with a function, and it crashed the application. I can't figure out why. Is there something wrong with my function?
//Legacy Macro
#define DEL_PTR(x) { if (x != nullptr){ delete x; } }

//My function
void delPtr(void * x) { if (x != nullptr){ delete x; } }


Forget about macros and naked new/deletes, this is "C++" not "C".  So refactor your codse to use std::unique_ptr at places where you need to control ownership of a pointer (in all the non-owning parts you can still pass on the raw pointers). Read up on anything related to pointers in the C++ core guidelines. But yes other then that use a function template

Also, void* p = new void; doesn't work.  The void type cannot be instantiated.  Which in turns means it cannot be destructed.

You are deleting pointers of the wrong type.
Consider that you are not actually deleting the pointer, but the pointee. Then it should be clear what the problem is: You attempt to delete objects of type void. Makes no sense.
You can write a template function that deduces the type of the pointer:
template <typename P>
void delPtr(P* ptr) {
     delete ptr;
}

The check for nullptr is superfluous.
You should not actually need such a function, because you should use smart pointers rather than manually managing the memory. Moreover there is no advantage of delPtr(x) compared to delete x;. It can be considered obfuscation. Perhaps the original author mistakenly assumed the nullptr check is needed and then mistakenly thought it would be a good idea to use a macro to shorten the code. You better get rid of this.

Maybe the macro was written at the time that the check was needed (or most people still believed it was needed). Up to C++98?

I would take a T*& and assign nullptr to it myself.

You never want to use a delete expression on a void* since we don't actually know what it points to.  Instead, use a function template like
template <typename T>
void delPtr(T* x) { if (x != nullptr){ delete x; } }

It should also be noted the nullptr check is not needed as delete is a non-op for null pointers.  That means the function can be simplified down to just
template <typename T>
void delPtr(T* x) { delete x; }

That said, manual memory management is a huge source of bugs and should be avoided if you can.  There are RAII smart pointers in C++ now like unique_ptr or shared_ptr that will delete the memory when they go out of scope for you.
